# Quiero poner un dominio .gt en firebase y mi proveedor de dns

Tags: firebase, dns

Quiero poner un dominio .gt en un hosting de firebase pero al configurarlo me dice que me contacte con el proveedor de dns y cuando me contacto con el proveedor de dns me dicen esto
Muchas gracias por la información. Le comento que los registros tipo A, CNAME, TXT, MX, entre otros registros, se configuran en archivo de zona de algun servidor DNS, al cual nosotros no tenemos acceso.

Intente buscar informacion en internet y no encuentro al respecto

Comment: Parece que le preguntaste al proveedor del hosting, pregúntale al proveedor del dominio.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, lecturas recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> aquí aprendes el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla. Por otro lado, unas clases de redes te caerían bien. ¿Has leído la documentación de firebase? ¿Sí? -> ¿Qué dice al respecto?. ¿No? -> A leerla. Algo ha de haber ahí. El proveedor del dominio te dará registros tipo "A" donde vas a colocar la IP del server al que apuntará el dominio.